# Custom _StoreMixin for dGrid not doing what it's supposed to do

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I have the following mixin declared in js/widgets/LoadAllStoreMixin.js:

```
define([ 'dojo/_base/declare', 'dgrid/_StoreMixin' ], function(declare,
        _StoreMixin) {
    return declare(_StoreMixin, {
        // summary:
        // dgrid mixin which implements the refresh method to
        // always perform a single query with no start or count
        // specified, to retrieve all relevant results at once.
        // Appropriate for grids using memory stores with small
        // result set sizes.

        refresh : function() {
            var self = this;

            // First defer to List#refresh to clear the grid's
            // previous content
            this.inherited(arguments);

            if (!this._renderedCollection) {
                return;
            }

            return this._trackError(function() {
                var queryResults = self._renderedCollection.fetch();
                queryResults.totalLength.then(function(total) {
                    // Record total so it can be retrieved later via
                    // get('total')
                    self._total = total;
                });
                return self.renderQueryResults(queryResults);
            });
        },

        renderArray : function() {
            var rows = this.inherited(arguments);

            // Clear _lastCollection which is ordinarily only used for
            // store-less grids
            this._lastCollection = null;

            return rows;
        }
    });
});
```

This is the same widget as written in http://dgrid.io/tutorials/0.4/single_query/ to allow an OnDemandList to load everything instead of just `minRowsPerPage` records. it is called like this:

```
var gridDataString = dom.byId("connectedEnvironmentsAndLevelsGridData").innerHTML;
eval("var connectedEnvironmentsAndLevelsGridJsonData=" + gridDataString);
var connectedEnvironmentsAndLevelsStore = new Memory( 
        { data: connectedEnvironmentsAndLevelsGridJsonData }
    );
var SelectionGrid = declare([ Grid, LoadAllStoreMixin, Selection, Keyboard, DijitRegistry]);
connectedEnvironmentsAndLevelsGrid = new SelectionGrid({
    store : connectedEnvironmentsAndLevelsStore,
    selectionMode : "toggle",
    columns : connectedEnvironmentsAndLevelsGridHeader,
    allowSelectAll : true,
    allowSelect: function(row) { 
        // disable the grid's rows basing on the phase compatibility
        // if true, the row selection is enabled, otherwise disabled
        return checkPhaseCompatibility(row);
    }
}, "connectedEnvironmentsAndLevelsGrid");
// Grid is an OnDemandGrid, not a normal grid.
```

It is loaded properly (so there's no issue with the `define([], function(){});` boilerplate), but for some reason, it returns in the `refresh()` in the first `if`, so it doesn't do what it's supposed to. I have no idea why this fails. Do I need to write more code than just the `refresh()` and `renderArray()` functions?

Answer (score 0):

You are using example from dgrid 0.4 version, I hope you are also using the same version of the api.

In 0.4 version, there the `store` property has been changed to `collection`

```
connectedEnvironmentsAndLevelsGrid = new SelectionGrid({
    collection : connectedEnvironmentsAndLevelsStore,
    selectionMode : "toggle",
    columns : connectedEnvironmentsAndLevelsGridHeader,
    allowSelectAll : true,
    allowSelect: function(row) { 
        // disable the grid's rows basing on the phase compatibility
        // if true, the row selection is enabled, otherwise disabled
        return checkPhaseCompatibility(row);
    }
}, "connectedEnvironmentsAndLevelsGrid");
```

UPDATE: If you are using 0.3version, example in th post will not work as there is no `_renderCollection` property in `_StoreMixin` in 0.3 version. Also, other properties are also missing like ' _total`, which is being used in this extension.

If you could let us known what you are trying to achieve then may be, we can provide alternative solutions.

Comment: I'm actually not sure what version of dgrid I'm using. It's probably earlier than 0.4 if it doesn't have collection yet. It's the version that comes with Dojo 1.8. We're not really able to change this version easily so I'll probably need an example from the dgrid version that comes with Dojo 1.8.

Comment: I checked the changeLog. We're using dGrid 0.3.14.

Comment: I am trying to load every item in the grid at the same time to fix an issue with SelectAll. I have managed to work around it by setting minRowsPerPage and maxRowsPerPage to `connectedEnvironmentsAndLevelsStore.data.length`.

Comment: @Nzall what's the issue with 'SelectAll'?

Comment: If you use an OnDemandGrid, it only loads part of the grid at a time, based on how much is visible. We have a window where you can select items to replace with a selectAll enabled, and the SelectAll would select them all, but they wouldn't be loaded into grid.Selection unless you scroll to the bottom of the grid. We also can't use the store in this case, because that gives issues if you first do SelectAll and then deselect some of them. We think that loading the entire grid at once is the best way, considering we only support desktops.

Comment: @Nzall If you do not want the lazyloading feature, You should simply use the `dgrid/Grid` instead of `dgrid/OnDemandGrid`, That's the only difference between them.